# What does it mean to "Blacklist" a tag and when should I request it?

Tags: discussion, faq, tags

More and more I see requests for blacklisting tags. However, I'm not sure what a tag blacklist is - or when it's appropriate to request one. On what cirucmstances should this be requested and how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be rare, and only when there is *overwhelming* data supporting the idea that "yes, there is a problem, this tag keep coming up and we can't make it go away."

Generally you should be using **tag synonyms** far more.